# How to check if a text field contains a word?

Tags: apex

For example

```
        trigger DisqualifyTestLeads on Lead (after insert, before update) {

        String testString = 'Test';
        for (Lead L : Trigger.New){
            if(L.Name.ContainsIgnoreCase(testString)){ 
            L.Status = 'Disqualified';
            }
    }
}
```

If the lead name contains the word test then the lead status is updated to Disqualified...

I just get a "method must have a body" error when i try this.

Comment: Can you post the complete Code so that we can have a closure look as Your code seems to be fine?

Answer (score 8):

> method must have a body

This usually means mismatched braces. It can occur when you have one too many braces elsewhere, so the compiler thinks you're trying to define a method. For example, the following code won't compile:

```
public class someClass {
  public void method();
}
```

Double-check the pairings of your open/close curly brackets.

---

```
String testString = 'Test';
for (Lead L : Trigger.New){
if(L.Name.Contains(testString)) 
    L.Status = 'Disqualified';
```

There's a lot wrong here:

```
for (Lead L : Trigger.New){
```

You have an opening `{`, but no closing `}`. If this was just because you didn't copy that part, then ignore this part, but I'm pretty sure you're missing a `}` somewhere.

---

```
if(L.Name.Contains(testString)) 
    L.Status = 'Disqualified';
```

This is a trap waiting to happen. Always use `{` and `}` around the statement for the if statement, even if there's only one. With some clever indentation and a lack of curly brackets, you can lead yourself into a trap:

```
if(L.Name.Contains(testString)) 
    L.Status = 'Disqualified';
    L.Email = 'invalid-email@example.com';
```

While you *think* that both of these statements might only execute if Name contains the string, the truth is, the Email field will *always* be set, because you forgot the curly brackets. Avoid this trap by getting in the habit:

```
if(L.Name.Contains(testString)) {
    L.Status = 'Disqualified';
    L.Email = 'invalid-email@example.com';
}
```

---

```
if(L.Name.Contains(testString)) {
```

This is a particularly clever trap waiting to happen; the Name field isn't automatically populated in some situations, like a Before Insert trigger, because it'a compound field. You shouldn't rely on that field being populated. This is true for Accounts (with Person Accounts), Contacts, and Leads. Other types of objects don't have that problem.

It's usually sufficient to just check the LastName, which is always a required field:

```
if(L.LastName.Contains(testString)) {
```

---

Finally, "contains" is case-sensitive. That means I can easily get around your code by writing "test" instead of "Test". For this specific case, consider using containsIgnoreCase:

```
if(L.LastName.containsIgnoreCase(testString)) {
```

---

Finally, keep in mind that you might be filtering out legitimate customers if you do this: the [Test](https://www.houseofnames.com/test-family-crest) clan, of which first migrated to the United States in the 17th century, has many different variations, including:

> ... Testa, Testi, Testini, Testino, Testoni, Testone, Testai, Testaj, Testani, Testabruna, Testadiferro, Testagrossa, Testaquadra ...

You might want to come up with a more elaborate method of filtering out test leads rather than depend on a specific name being entered, such as using a custom field or something else.

Comment: @sfdcfoxthank thank you;  I'm still getting the "method must have body" error, what i have in total is this                                                    
                                                                                                                            
 trigger DisqualifyTestLeads on Lead (after insert, before update) {
   
  String testString = 'Test';
    for (Lead L : Trigger.New){
               if(L.Name.ContainsIgnoreCase(testString)){ 
                L.Status = 'Disqualified';
                }
     }
}

Comment: @enossir It needs to be "before insert" instead of "after insert", or you'll get a FinalException error.

Comment: @enossir Wait, are you trying to create a *class* or a *trigger*?

Comment: I'm trying to create a  trigger.

Comment: @enossir Well, your trigger code, as written, works just fine. I think you've probably put the file in the wrong place or something.

Answer (score 0):

The above should work. Is it an issue of missing brackets at the end of your if statement? Also, Trigger.new returns an array of SObjects. Do you need to cast this into an array of Leads? Hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code. The following debugs as expected.

```
String testString = 'world';
Account a = new Account(Name='hello world');
if (a.Name.contains(testString)) {
    System.debug('works');
}
```